# Bash string parsing, skewed by internal strings

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string in my bash shell like:

`out=$(su - user -c "someCommand -f 'string text "problemString"'")`

The problem here is that it's getting parsed as so:

`out=\$(su - user -c \"someCommand -f 'string text \"problemString\"'\")`

I don't want `"problemString"` to be parsed out -- i.e., it needs to stay exactly as-is, including the quotes. How can I do that?

**Update:** I've attempted to escape the inner `"` with:

`out=$(su - user -c "someCommand -f 'string text \"problemString\"'")`,

but when the command is executed on the host machine, it returns an error from `someCommand`:

`Unknown command '\p'`

**Update 2:**

Real example:

`OUTPUT=$(su - mysql -c "mysql --skip-column-names --raw --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=user--password=pass -e 'show variables where variable_name = \"max_connections\"'")`

I'm passing this bash script via fabric in Python:

```
# probably not relevant, but just in case..
def ParseShellScripts(runPath, commands):
    for i in range(len(commands)):
        if commands[i].startswith('{shell}'):
            # todo: add validation/logging for directory `sh` and that scripts actually exist
            with open(os.path.join(runPath, 'sh', commands[i][7:]),"r") as shellFile:
                commands[i] = shellFile.read()
                print commands[i]
    return commands
```

This prints:

`OUTPUT=$(su - mysql -c "mysql --skip-column-names --raw --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=pluto_user --password=pluto_user -e 'show variables where variable_name = \"max_connections\"'")`

which then gets executed on some remote box via fabric, which results in `ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\m'.`

Comment: How are you getting this string and how are you using it?

Comment: `"someCommand -f 'string text \"problemString\"'"`

Comment: You're inside double quotes so you need to escape double quotes. The single quotes around it don't change a thing from the point of the `$()` context.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example that doesn't work for you and is reproducible (i.e. uses a ubiquitous "someCommand")?

Comment: I've added more details, thanks

Comment: It's not a bash issue. In fact your Python output works fine on my shell (if I substitute my credentials for yours). The '\m' thing looks like a mysql bug, judging by a quick web search.

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
out=$(su - user -c "someCommand -f 'string text \"problemString\"'")
```

Comment: When doing this, I get a message from `someCommand`: `Unknown command '\p'.` So it's like it's still removing the `"`, and keeping the `\`

Comment: Then something about what you're actually doing doesn't match what you asked.  This is all literal strings, right?  If any of these are in variables, that changes everything.

Comment: Yeah, none of them are in variables... I'll update my question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use single quotes. Strings in single quotes don't get parsed or interpreted. For instance:

```
echo 'a"b'
```

outputs:

```
a"b
```

Because no parsing occurs.

For reference: [bash manual on quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes).